# React input loses focus on onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

I'm making a React application and I need a table where each row contains an input. For that, I'm using Material-UI and Formik, but I have a bug that anytime I type something in one of the inputs, I lose the focus of that input. I saw this bug a lot on the internet, I tried with adding keys, deleting keys, use defaultValue instead of value, and anything worked properly for me.

I've created a codesandbox for this: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-robinson-i69v3?file=/src/App.js

If anyone could help me I would really appreciate, I'm stuck with this problems for a few days.

Comment: Something similar happened to me once, try adding a `FormControl` around your input

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: can you provide a codesanbox with your code?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-robinson-i69v3?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Everytime your `MyInput` components rerenders, it key changes because it's non deterministic (it uses `Math.random()`). Because of this, React will remove the existing DOM node and insert a new DOM node in it's place. Your browser now thinks it's an other element, so it does not put focus on that element.

Comment: allright, and what do you suggest??

Comment: You can use the index from the map function that renders the inputs as a key

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set the `key` property on every component. It's just needed where you output an array of elements, e.g. when using `map`. So in your example only the `Formik` component needs to have the key property set, because it's the parent of the other components inside the loop.

```js
     {companies.map((company, index) => (
          <Formik
            key={index}
            initialValues={{
              contact_name: company.contact_name || "",
              contact_email: company.contact_email || ""
            }}
            onSubmit={(values) => {
              console.log(values);
            }}
          >
            {(formik) => (
...
```